# Any Open source download managers?

Tags: windows, download-manager

I am regular user of flash get and i am happy with that. But recent times I am downloading lot of videos from youtube. Flashget doesn't support youtube downloads and I would like to write my own based on some open source download managers . Is there any open source download managers and free download manager which can support pluings/addons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) is open source too.

Comment: I'll go with this :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a Firefox extension, but (the hideously named) [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/).  Dunno about plugins, though.

Comment: DownThemAll is good , But it can't split the downloads to make it fast to download

Comment: You mean download different parts of the same file with different connections?  Sure it can.  Right-click on the download and select Misc &rarr; One More Segment.

Comment: Wow.  Not even HTML character entities, huh?  The default number of segments is confusingly titled "Max. number of segments per download" in the Advanced tab of its preferences.

Comment: → entering the characters directly works fine, though. Who needs HTML character entities anyway? :þ

Comment: I don't really feel like memorizing the whole Unicode chart.

Answer (score 2):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)

> **GNU General Public License**
> Free download manager is now open-source software released under GNU GPL.
>
> **Increase your download speed and resume broken downloads**
> FDM accelerates downloads by splitting files into sections and then downloading them simultaneously. As a result download speed increases up to 600%, or even more! FDM can also resume broken downloads so you needn`t start downloading from the beginning after casual interruption.
>
> **Flash video download**
> Download video from video sites, such as Youtube, Google Video, etc. The video can then be saved in native .flv format or converted to one of more popular video formats.
>
> **HTTP/FTP/BitTorrent support**
> FDM lets you download files and whole web sites from any remote server via HTTP, HTTPS and FTP.
> You can also download files using BitTorrent protocol.

Answer (score 0):

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), the command line based (don't let that put you off, it just means you don't have to look through the GUI code when you're reading it, right?), GNU Download manager. There's an equally good windows version [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), which quickly became my downloader of choice for any file larger than a few hundred megabytes.

Comment: aria2 often does the job much better than wget. wget can't do concurrent downloads.

Answer (score 0):

[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) is the best for me. It supports addon like Firefox.

> JDownloader is open source, platform independent, and written
>   completely in Java. It simplifies downloading files from
>   One-Click-Hosters like Rapidshare.com or Megaupload.com - not only for
>   users with a premium account but also for users who don't pay. It
>   offers downloading in multiple parallel streams, captcha recognition,
>   automated file extraction, and much more. Of course, JDownloader is
>   absolutely free of charge. Additionally, many "link encryption" sites
>   are supported - so you just paste the "encrypted" links and JD does
>   the rest. JDownloader can import CCF, RSDF and the new DLC files.

Answer (score 0):

For youtube, you can use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.