# Windows downloader with automatic speed throttle

Tags: windows, software-rec, download-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download manager to replace GetRight?](https://superuser.com/questions/11874/download-manager-to-replace-getright)

I've tried many download managers during the past years but haven't found any that can effectively offer an "automatic speed" option. I want maximum download speed while browsing web should still be comfortable.

I'm using Windows 7 now and found information about the [BITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) service. I even tried some downloaders which utilize this technology, but it's too slow and developed on an older versions of BITS.

Are there any fast downloaders with effective bandwidth throttling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download manager to replace GetRight?](http://superuser.com/questions/11874/download-manager-to-replace-getright) and/or [Any Open source download managers?](http://superuser.com/questions/50670/any-open-source-download-managers)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/).

It's designed to download files from one-click file hosting services like Rapidshare, but does a good job for simple HTTP downloads too. You can throttle the bandwidth, set how many connections should be open simultaneously and with a Firefox add-on you can parse websites for links to download

Comment: JDownloader doesn't have such option at all.

Comment: sorry looke like i either didnt read the question properly or it was edited after i answered. since you tried BITS already, the only other thing i could think of is QoS flags for your network packets. depending on your network hardware you can create individual rules for packages and what priority they have. but most routers just check like the port or protocol, so it cant distinguish http downloads from websites. but it can do things like priorize gaming or VOIP over torrents or FTP downloads